# How do I add documentation to a matlab package?

Tags: matlab, namespaces, documentation

Say I have the following file structure:

```
+mypackage/
  foo.m
  bar.m
```

How can I add help to the output of `help(mypackage)`?

In python, I'd just add a docstring in `__init__.py`. What's the equivalent here?

Comment: See: [Create Help Summary Files](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-a-help-summary-contents-m.html)

Comment: Helpfully the matlab pages trap me in a login redirect loop and fail to load for me

Comment: Then adjust your browser settings. MATLAB's documentation does not require a login.

Comment: @excaza: Not so much a browser setting as a cookie left by mathworks that causes it to get confused. At any rate, what I was pushing for there was a non-link-only answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per MATLAB's [toolbox distribution documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating-help.html), the MATLAB analog to Python's `__init__.py` docstring would be a [help summary file](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-a-help-summary-contents-m.html).

Using the above folder structure, we can add a `contents.m` file to achieve the desired behavior:

```
+mypackage/
  foo.m
  bar.m
  contents.m
```

Given a basic `contents.m` file:

```
% This is contents.m
% This package contains:
%     bar - Bar things
%     foo - Foo things
```

We achieve the following:

```
>> help mypackage
  This is contents.m
  This package contains:
      bar - Bar things
      foo - Foo things
```